# \neq (not equal) command does not work anymore

Tags: errors

I experience the following LaTeX-Preamble, which causes the "\neq" command to cause an error.

Has anyone experienced similar things before or an idea why this might happen?

Some Info:
- TeX: MikTex 2.9, 64 bit
- System: Windows 7, 64

I suppose it is some of the maths packages I load, but was not able to figure it out.
I tried:
- Putting amsmath, amssymb, mathabx at the end
- not loading maths packages
- Re-Installing MikTex
- using "\ne", "\nequal" , "\not="
No luck.

This the (sorry, quite long) preamble (edited after the answer to make it shorter and more relevant):

```tex
    \documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}
    \usepackage{cogsci} %


    %_______________________________________________________________________________
    %__MATH
    %__MATH_GENERAL
    \usepackage{amsmath, amssymb} %         % mathematical extensions
    \usepackage[mathb]{mathabx} %           % font for maths symbols e.g. \corresponds
    \usepackage{bm}             % for boldface greek letters in math
```

Comment: (1) make a minimal example, the above is not minimal, and (2) make something that can be copied and pasted. In many cases the process of removing stuff from the preamble while still having the error, will lead you to figure out what the error is. Plus the `cogsci` package is not a standard package

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is caused by

```
\usepackage[mathb]{mathabx}
```

because the required macro `\notsign` is defined only with the `matha` option. Solutions:

1. Don't load `mathabx`;
2. Issue `\changenotsign` after loading it.